# Excel graph not showing some x value labels

Tags: worksheet-function, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

My x-axis for an Excel graph is missing some labels
and I cannot figure out why.

More specifically, my x-axis is supposed to look like this
(I will bold some of them so it's easier to read):

> **50, 100, 150, ..., 500**, 50, 100, 150, ..., 500, **50, 100, 150, ..., 500**, 50, 100, 150, ..., 500, **50, 100, 150, ..., 500**, 50,
> 100, 150, ..., 500, **50, 100, 150, ..., 500**, 50, 100, 150, ..., 500

Instead, it looks like this:

> **50, 100, 150, ..., 450**, 50, 100, 150, ..., 450, **50, 100, 150, ..., 450**, 50, 100, 150, ..., 450, **50, 100, 150, ..., 450**, 50,
> 100, 150, ..., 450, **50, 100, 150, ..., 450**, 50, 100, 150, ..., 450

So it skips the number 500. 
I made sure that the label 500 was checked in the category filter
so it would appear on the graph. 
I also searched online but cannot find a solution. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

The graph shows the percentage improvement for 80 different cases. 
(The percentage improvement is the y-axis
and the 80 different cases are on the x-axis).

The reason why I have 50, ..., 500 repeated 8 times is because
I'm looking at 8 different scenarios for the cases 50, ... , 500. 
(So we have 8*10 = 80 different cases in total.)

To create the chart, set up data like this in the worksheet:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | 51.61440739 |
| 100 | 105.2234802 |
| 150 | 153.4851506 |
| ︙ | ︙ |

***where the data in the* `X` *column are formatted as text.*** 
Then create a Line chart, using defaults throughout.

**Below is a screenshot of how the label 500 is checked:**

[image]

Comment: Can you include some screenshots to better diagnose please.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I added a screenshot

Comment: A screenshot of the chart isn’t very helpful. Please tell/show us more of how you’re getting the chart; i.e., show us your data and maybe some of the chart properties. You say “I made sure that the label 500 was checked”; tell us and/or show us where you did that.

Comment: @Scott I tried to clarify the question and added another screenshot to show how I checked 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re misrepresenting the problem. 
You say,

> … my x-axis … looks like this:
> **50, 100, 150, ..., 450**, 50, 100, 150, ..., 450, **50, 100, 150, ..., 450**, …

… when in fact it looks like

> **50, 150, 250, 350, 450**, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, **50, 150, 250, 350, 450**, …

It’s not skipping just 500; it’s skipping 100, 200, 300 and 400 also. 
So it’s a good thing that you posted the image of the chart! 
Here is a detail from your image:

[image: Excerpt of OP's illustration]

In other words, it’s skipping *every other* value. 
It’s doing so because, at the scale and format you are using,
there isn’t room to display all the labels.

---

I was able to (roughly) reproduce your chart:

[image: My chart that looks sort-of like the OP’s chart]

I found three ways to display all the X values (labels).

1. Simply stretch the chart so there’s more room:

   [image: My chart, but stretched (horizontally)]
2. Make the labels smaller. 
   Right-click on one of the labels (“50”, “150”, “250”, etc.), select “Font…”,
   and set the font size smaller. 
   The above two images use 9 pt. text (the default); this uses 6 pt.:

   [image: My chart, but with labels using 6 pt. text]
3. Tell Excel to display all the labels. 
   Right-click on the X (horizontal) axis and select “Format Axis…”.
   A “Format Axis” panel will appear (on the right side of your window). 
   Click the fourth (last) icon, with hover-text “Axis Options”,
   if it isn’t already selected. 
   Scroll down to “**LABELS**” and expand it. 
   Change the “Interval between labels” to 1:

   [image: “Format Axis” dialog]

   Excel automatically turns the text vertical to make it fit:

   [image: My chart, but forcing all the labels to appear]